# Is there a Ed25519 threshold signature protocol similar to the Gennaro-Goldfeder schema for ECDSA?

Tags: ed25519, schnorr-signature, threshold-cryptography

I keep searching online and asking in different cryptographic communities whether there is a similar threshold signature schema (or a close one) to what [Gennaro and Goldfeder](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/114.pdf) proposed for ECDSA?

Requirements for this Ed25519 threshold signature schema am looking for is:

- **Each party generates a key share secretly and independently**
- **Parties never reveal their key share**
- **Schema support m-of-t signers**
- **Signature can be verified using [existing verification algorithms](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8032)**

I've seen the following materials so far, but is hard for me to understand whether they are matching above mentioned conditions:

- [Aggregated Ed25519 Signatures](https://github.com/ZenGo-X/multi-party-eddsa/wiki/Aggregated-Ed25519-Signatures)
- [Accountable-Subgroup Multisignatures](https://www.cs.bu.edu/%7Ereyzin/papers/multisig.pdf)
- [Provably Seure Distributed Shnorr Signatures and a (t; n) Threshold
  Sheme for Impliit Certiates](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/techreports/2001/corr2001-13.ps)
- [Simple Schnorr Multi-Signatures
  with Applications to Bitcoin](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/068.pdf)

I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hallambaker-threshold-sigs-00 does this help?